# Problem with one of the order property proofs

Tags: analysis, real-numbers

I came across an exercise in an analysis book that requires me to show that

if $A$ is a real number such that $0 \leq A \leq B$ for every $B>0$, then $A=0$

What I fail to understand here is if $B>0$, and if $B=A$, shouldn't $A>0$ be true?

Comment: You must be careful about the order of your quantifiers.  $A$ is defined before $B$, so $A$ must be fixed and unchanging, before choosing $B$.  On the other hand, $B$ is chosen after $A$, so you can choose $B$ to be anything you want (perhaps $A=B$, perhaps not).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $0\le A\le B$ for *every* positive real number $B$. As the equation says $A\le B$, it *may* (a priori) happen that $A=B$. However, as the proof will finally show, we have $A=0$ and hence *cannot* have $A=B$ if $B>0$.

Answer (score 0):

The important idea here is that the relation

$(1):$ $0\leq A\leq B$ holds $\textit {for all}$  $B>0$.

Now suppose that $A\neq 0$. Then $A=c$ for some $c>0$. But then if we take $B=c/2>0$ we get a contradiction because in this case, $A>B$ which violates $(1)$.